# How to read application.properties in Java code

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

Hi I would like to read values from application.properties. I have found that this should work:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        Environment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        System.out.println("STARTING:");
        System.out.println("Connecting to: "+environment.getProperty("datasource"));
    }
```

but I am getting null for datasource value.

my application-context.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
</beans>
```

could someone tell me where could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog.
https://zetcode.com/spring/propertyplaceholder/

This will explain to you how you can to use the application.properties values.

Please Map your been with "application.properties" values

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.
    SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"></property>
</bean>
```

and Use

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    var ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("my-beans.xml");

    var dataSource = (SimpleDriverDataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");

    logger.info("Url: {}", dataSource.getUrl());
    logger.info("User name: {}", dataSource.getUsername());
    logger.info("Password: {}", dataSource.getPassword());

    ctx.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have already seen this blok, but it is not solving what I want. I am able to use the application.properties in application-context.xml but I am not able to read those values from Java code.